# Change property FeatureCollection

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am working on land-use classification and I would like to merge some classes from my training dataset. I've a FeatureCollection with over a hundred polygons (features), with all of them having a property 'class' to them with a number from 1 to 17 representing the different classes. I would like to replace from all Features the property which have a class 8 to be replaced by class 9.

I've been trying different things, and I think it should look something like this:

```
var conditional = function(image){
  return ee.Algorithms.If(ee.Number(image.get('class').eq(8)),
  image.set({class: 9}),
  image)

var test = table.map(conditional)
```

In which:

- table contains my FeatureCollection with polygons
- class is the property on which the conditional function must be based
- 8 and 9 are linked to the 'class' properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You function is fine, you just need to move one parenthesis, from `ee.Number(image.get('class').eq(8))` to `ee.Number(image.get('class')).eq(8)`. Also, in the code you posted you are missing the closing bracket.

As a suggestion, I wouldn't use `image` for that function argument, it's confusing because when you loop (`map`) over a `FeatureCollection` each element is a `Feature`, so I'd use `feat`, but of course it works with any name you use, and that is up to you.

```js
var conditional = function(feat) {
  return ee.Algorithms.If(ee.Number(feat.get('class')).eq(8),
  feat.set({class: 9}),
  feat)
}
var test = table.map(conditional)
```

Comment: To group multiple classes it is possible to repeat this process. Can I however also add an `.or` statement to add class 7 to be transformed into 9 too?

Comment: yes, in `ee.Algorithms.If` you can use any condition you want